# 3 state checkbox binding in mvvm, unable to set null state

Tags: xaml, checkbox, mvvm, data-binding, uwp

I am creating a UWP app using MVVM. In my xaml view,I have a 3 state checkbox. My checkbox is inside a ListView, and this listview also has a sub-list view, with more checkboxes - so essentially nested list of checkboxes. I am trying to get my checkbox  in the outer listview to be in the null state if any of the checkboxes in the inner listview is selected. If all the inner ones are selected, I want the outer checkbox to be in true state, and if none are selected, I want it to be in false state. I'm using delegate commands for implementing these event handlers.

I am successfully able to get the true and false cases to work, but I am unable to get the checkbox to show state null on the UI, where as it's value in my ViewModel successfully changes to null.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ObxList, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox IsChecked="{x:Bind IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" IsThreeState="True" Command="{Binding DataContext.ClickCommand, ElementName=Y}">
                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Value}"  />
            </CheckBox>
            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Children}" Visibility="{Binding visibility, Mode=TwoWay}">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                  IsThreeState="False" Command="{Binding DataContext.ChildCommand, ElementName=Y}">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}"/>
                        </CheckBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView
```

Here is the code of the ViewModel method that is being called in my delegate command:

```
public void ChildCheckboxHandler()
    {
        // gets all of the lowest level children
        foreach (Object item in AllObjectsList.Where(t =>
        {
            return t.Children.Count() == 0;
        }))
        {
            if (item.IsSelected == true)
            {
                var parent = item.GetParent(AllObjectsList);
                if (parent.IsSelected == null || parent.IsSelected == false)
                {
                    // checks if all children are selected
                    // and changes the parent to true if so
                    // null if only some are selected
                    bool allChildrenSelected = true;
                    foreach (var child in parent.GetChildren(AllObjectsList))
                    {
                        if (child.IsSelected == false)
                        {
                            allChildrenSelected = false;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (allChildrenSelected)
                    {
                        parent.IsSelected = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        parent.IsSelected = new Nullable<Boolean>();

                    }
                }
            }
            else if (item.IsSelected == false)
            {
                var parent = item.GetParent(AllObjectsList);
                if (parent.IsSelected == null)
                {
                    // checks if all the children are unchecked
                    // if they are, then sets the parent to false
                    // if they are not, then sets the parent to null
                    bool noChildrenSelected = true;
                    foreach (var child in parent.GetChildren(AllObjectsList))
                    {
                        if (child.IsSelected == true)
                        {
                            noChildrenSelected = false;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (noChildrenSelected)
                    {
                        parent.IsSelected = false;
                    }
                }
                else if (parent.IsSelected == true)
                {
                    parent.IsSelected = null;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

This is because binding to nullable types is not supported in WinRT.

@Jerry Nixon - MSFT has a [blog](http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2014/07/lets-code-in-winrt-xaml-you-cannot.html) to workaround this issue in 3 ways, and samples are provided in his blog.

Comment: All the Codeplex links in that article are now dead.

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately the issue is the `DependencyProperty` implementation of `CheckBox.IsChecked`. Nullable primitive type bindings are not implicitly supported in WinRT, in WinRT the underlying type is `IReference1<Boolean>` which is an internal definition so we cannot use simple type converters to work around this.

> The [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33161842/1690217) is technically correct, @Jerry Nixon provides some useful background information in the [linked article](http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2014/07/lets-code-in-winrt-xaml-you-cannot.html), but it only demonstrates that there *are* workarounds, and not specifically _how to implement them.

The advice in this post is still relevant in UWP almost 10 years on: [Windows 8 Dev Tip: Nullable Dependency Properties and Binding](https://www.danrigby.com/2012/07/24/windows-8-dev-tip-nullable-dependency-properties-and-binding/). The easiest work around is to create a new Dependency Property that is typed as an `Object`.

> This is a common solution in many 3rd party control libraries, it is common to find an `object` typed `Value` property and a separately *typed* property.

This *can* be achieved through an Attached Property, however I prefer extending the `CheckBox` class:

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Check Box Control with support for binding with an indeterminate state
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>https://www.danrigby.com/2012/07/24/windows-8-dev-tip-nullable-dependency-properties-and-binding/</remarks>
public class BindableCheckBox : CheckBox
{
    public BindableCheckBox()
    {
        this.IsThreeState = true;
        // start in the nullable state!
        this.IsChecked = null;

        // hook up UI events to manually set the value appropriately
        this.Checked += BindableCheckBox_Checked;
        this.Unchecked += BindableCheckBox_Unchecked;
        this.Indeterminate += BindableCheckBox_Indeterminate;

        // Hookup property changed event, in case some moron sets the IsChecked some other way
        this.RegisterPropertyChangedCallback(CheckBox.IsCheckedProperty, (s, e) =>
        {
            if (s is BindableCheckBox cb)
            {
                if (!cb._ValueIsChanging)
                {
                    var newValue = (bool?)s.GetValue(e);
                    if (cb.State != newValue)
                        cb.State = newValue;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private bool _ValueIsChanging = false;
    private void BindableCheckBox_Indeterminate(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(!_ValueIsChanging)
            Value = null;
    }

    private void BindableCheckBox_Unchecked(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!_ValueIsChanging)
            Value = false;
    }

    private void BindableCheckBox_Checked(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!_ValueIsChanging)
            Value = true;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// DP For the Three States of this checkbox, Null implies that it is in the Indeterminate state
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
           nameof(Value),
           typeof(object),
           typeof(BindableCheckBox), new PropertyMetadata(null, (s, e) =>
           {
               if (s is BindableCheckBox cb)
               {
                   try
                   {
                       cb._ValueIsChanging = true;
                       var newValue = (bool?)e.NewValue;
                       if (cb.IsChecked != newValue)
                           cb.IsChecked = newValue;
                   }
                   finally
                   {
                       cb._ValueIsChanging = false;
                   }
               }
           }));

    /// <summary>
    /// Value property, a bindable implementation of IsChecked
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>You should bind this property INSTEAD of IsChecked, if you want to bind to the indeterminate state</remarks>
    public bool? Value
    {
        get { return (bool?)GetValue(ValueProperty); }
        private set { SetValue(ValueProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

Now you can bind to the `Value` property with *TwoWay* bindings in MVVM style